# What is wrong with my Morris Traversal code?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to recover a binary search tree using morris traversal.

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) {
 *      val = x;
 *      left=null;
 *      right=null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
public TreeNode rmt(TreeNode leftNode, TreeNode currNode){
    if(leftNode.right!=null && leftNode.right!=currNode){
        leftNode=leftNode.right;
    }
    return leftNode;
}
public ArrayList<Integer> recoverTree(TreeNode A) {
    TreeNode currNode = A;
    TreeNode a=null;
    TreeNode b=null;
    TreeNode prevNode=null;
    while(currNode!=null){
        TreeNode leftNode = currNode.left;
        if(leftNode==null){
            if(prevNode!=null && prevNode.val>currNode.val){
                if(a==null){
                    a=prevNode;
                }
                b=currNode;
            }
            prevNode=currNode;
            currNode=currNode.right;
        }else{
            TreeNode rightNode = rmt(leftNode,currNode);
            if(rightNode.right==null){
                rightNode.right=currNode;
                currNode=currNode.left;
            }else{
                rightNode.right=null;
                if(prevNode!=null && prevNode.val>currNode.val){
                    if(a==null){
                        a=prevNode;
                    }
                    b=currNode;
                }
                prevNode=currNode;
                currNode=currNode.right;
            }
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(a.val);
    arr.add(b.val);
    return arr;
}
}
```

It is saying -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Solution.recoverTree(Solution.java:56)
    at Main.main(Main.java:329)
Your submission failed for the following input
535 344 162 345 152 181 -1 -1 106 161 173 261 92 133 157 -1 165 178 256 329 86 104 108 137 154 160 163 171 174 179 210 258 265 335 83 87 102 105 107 114 134 147 153 155 159 -1 -1 164 170 172 -1 176 -1 180 182 221 257 259 264 311 334 337 80 85 -1 90 96 103 -1 -1 -1 -1 109 132 -1 135 144 148 -1 -1 -1 156 158 -1 -1 -1 167 -1 -1 -1 175 177 -1 -1 -1 202 219 223 -1 -1 -1 260 262 -1 278 314 331 -1 336 339 79 82 84 -1 88 91 93 97 -1 -1 -1 113 117 -1 -1 136 139 145 -1 150 -1 -1 -1 -1 166 168 -1 -1 -1 -1 186 208 214 220 222 245 -1 -1 -1 263 269 304 313 319 330 333 -1 -1 338 341 -1 -1 81 -1 -1 -1 -1 89 -1 -1 -1 95 -1 98 110 -1 115 125 -1 -1 138 141 -1 146 149 151 -1 -1 -1 169 185 193 203 209 213 218 -1 -1 -1 -1 241 247 -1 -1 268 276 297 307 312 -1 317 328 -1 -1 332 -1 -1 -1 340 343 -1 -1 -1 -1 94 -1 -1 99 -1 111 116 -1 120 128 -1 -1 140 142 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 184 -1 192 198 -1 206 -1 -1 211 -1 215 -1 224 244 246 250 267 -1 275 277 291 299 306 308 -1 -1 316 318 320 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 342 -1 -1 -1 -1 101 -1 112 -1 -1 118 122 126 130 -1 -1 -1 143 183 -1 189 -1 195 200 205 207 -1 212 -1 217 -1 227 243 -1 -1 -1 248 251 266 -1 274 -1 -1 -1 281 295 298 301 305 -1 -1 309 315 -1 -1 -1 -1 323 -1 -1 100 -1 -1 -1 -1 119 121 124 -1 127 129 131 -1 -1 -1 -1 187 190 194 196 199 201 204 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 216 -1 226 239 242 -1 -1 249 -1 253 -1 -1 270 -1 280 290 294 296 -1 -1 300 302 -1 -1 -1 310 -1 -1 321 325 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 123 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 188 -1 191 -1 -1 -1 197 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 225 -1 231 240 -1 -1 -1 -1 252 254 -1 272 279 -1 283 -1 292 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 303 -1 -1 -1 322 324 327 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 228 232 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 255 271 273 -1 -1 282 284 -1 293 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 326 -1 -1 229 -1 238 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 285 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 230 237 -1 -1 287 -1 -1 235 -1 286 288 233 236 -1 -1 -1 289 -1 234 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

I am not able to understand what is wrong here. I think there is some problem with assignment of a and b or it have some problem with leftNode being null.Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: What tree does that "following input" represent? Can you provide the code that builds that tree and calls your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in the `rmt` function.

The purpose of this function is to find the predecessor node of `currNode`, (with the `leftNode` already provided as argument), but it fails to do that when `leftNode` has a right-right grandchild and `currNode` is further down that subtree. In that case the function wrongly returns `leftNode->right`, while the predecessor of `currNode` is not that node, but is located in the right subtree of that node.

The fix is to turn the `if` statement into a `while` statement:

```
    public TreeNode rmt(TreeNode leftNode, TreeNode currNode){
        // Fix: while instead of if
        while (leftNode.right != null && leftNode.right != currNode) {
            leftNode = leftNode.right;
        }
        return leftNode;
    }
```

I would also suggest giving this function a more telling name. I have no clue what `rmt` means, and would suggest `get_predecessor` or something similar.